# What is this military aircraft from the James Bond film Octopussy?

Tags: aircraft-identification, aviation-in-fiction

The James Bond 1983 adventure [Octopussy](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086034/) opens with Bond flying through a hangar in a [Bede BD-5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bede_BD-5) and generally causing carnage. One of the planes I cannot identify.

[image: Octopussy 1983 (1)]
[image: Octopussy 1983 (2)]

It is possible that it is a smorgasbord of aircraft bits, of course.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is such thing as the [Internet Movie Plane Database](http://impdb.org/index.php?title=The_Internet_Movie_Plane_Database) which has a page for [Octopussy](http://impdb.org/index.php?title=Octopussy)

It includes this picture:
[image]

which it lists as:

> Modified nose section of a Dutch built Hawker Hunter, serial N-202. Also seen in The Man with the Golden Gun.

Comment: A quick google will show that those are not the inlets of a Hawker Hunter -- unless substantial modifications were done.

The inlets look quite small - and the splitter plate seems very close to the side of body.  Maybe it is a bit of Hollywood magic.

Comment: I was unaware of the IMPDB, thank you.   There's a IMcarDB and a IMfirearmsDB in addition to the original IMDB; I wonder what other databases of movie "things" there are....

Comment: @RobMcDonald I agree it looks nothing like the inlets of a hunter. Just repeating a piece of evidence I found. I suspect its just the props department making it look more aeroplane-y

Comment: The inlets bear a passing resemblance to a Jaguar, which was a bit newer at the time. Wouldn't be a surprise if the props guys "updated" it with plywood and filler, as long as it was never going to fly again.

Comment: Sure, it would be a commonplace that, in passing, the director or art director might randomly comment to a grip or someone "throw something on that hole thing there so it looks cooler".  (note that movie "magic", ie cgi etc, was not part of the universe then.)

Comment: No good engineer would fit a straight splitter plate to a rounded fuselage side. Those clearly were added by a gifted amateur.

Comment: @PeterKämpf: the ones of the [F-4](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_F-4_Phantom_II#/media/File%3AQF-4_Holloman_AFB.jpg) were actually straight... but it were in the '50s 

Comment: The F-4 splitter plates were straight because they were hinged in the middle to allow them to be used to modify the inlet flow at speeds above about M1.6 to ensure subsonic flow at the compression face.

Answer (score 4):

I think the short answer is it's not a real aircraft. It looks like a prop. It bears the closest resemblance to me to the McDonnell Douglass F-4 Phantom II, but shares a few commonalities with the Hunter also (might be a prop built around the remains of N-202 as suggested above?).

One indicator it might be a F-4 is the inverted-teardrop-shaped flat front cockpit glass which was common on US fighter aircraft of the era such as the F-4, A-6 Intruder (in a distinctive side-by-side pair) and F-14 Tomcat which allowed a clear FoV for the HUD, but this glass shape was also fitted on a lot of Hunters for the same purpose, and the cockpit itself looks very Hunter-shaped and is only a single-seater.

Another is the large side intakes on the fuselage with the 'barge board' up against the cockpit (I don't know the actual term). The scale and proportion of these are not particularly accurate to the F-4, but the shape is very distinctive.

The nose also has the wrong profile and taper for a Hunter, but it might have been altered to look more 'modern'. It looks a lot more like a F-4 Phantom nose with the black nose cone being a common feature on early F-4s.

In the lower picture it also looks like it has a catapult bar on the nose gear (although the gear itself doesn't look carrier grade!)

Obvious 'not and F-4' things are lack of the tandem 2-seater cockpit, I can't see well in the screen-grab but it looks like the wing profiles are way off.

EDIT: Looking more deeply into it, it may also have drawn inspiration from the Avro Arrow and British TSR-2 prototypes.

Definitely a 'smorgasbord of aircraft bits' and a lot of imagination that's sort of an F-4 but not really!

Comment: Note the super-realistic glowing u-shaped tube in the radar dish!

Comment: That’s so the technician can see in the super-dark poorly lit hangar xD